# Prevent Form submission upon back button in Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

i have the application where after hitting back button of browser it says "Confirm Form submission" , as i don't want that to happen..any suggestion for this? 
i have written something like that in servlet.. `response2.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store");
        response2.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        response2.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response2.setHeader("Expires", "-1");
        response2.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response2.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
        response2.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        response2.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
        response2.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
        response2.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);`

How to handle this one..should i save the cache or not? is this happening because of cache is not being stored ?

Comment: You should use the PRG pattern to avoid form re-submission: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: You can send form using ajax.

Comment: @Oscar will that also stop form resubmission on multiple back button?  (ie click back on the Get and then back on the Post)?